# Why DateTime.TryParse is receive error for simple input?

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime, tryparse

Why this code is receiving error for input like "8:16AM":

```
        string time = Console.ReadLine();
        DateTime outValue = DateTime.MinValue;

        bool error = DateTime.TryParseExact(time, "HH:mmtt" /*"hh:mmtt"*/, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out outValue);

        Console.WriteLine(error);
        Console.WriteLine(outValue);
        Console.Read();
```

What should I set in order to accept such an input "8:16" and convert it to DateTime object ?

Comment: This is working however I am receiving from API time in format 8:16AM.
Ok I may fill missing 0 in front. That is not a big deal, however I guess 8:16AM could be acceptable as well by msdn. 
Thanks for answer. Have a good day :)

Comment: Ok I have defined format by myself. It was not so smart from my side. I would fill such a 0. Thanks.

Comment: don't forget to accept the answer (by Jamiec)

Answer (score 5):

You've used `HH` which expects a 2 digit hour. You can either pass `08:16AM` or change your `HH` to `H`.

Live example: http://rextester.com/IPNS3820

Comment: Yes, you are right, I have defined format by myself. I am going to fill such a 0.

Answer (score 1):

It's caused by expecting two digits for hours.

You can add leading zero if it's missing.

```
    string time = Console.ReadLine();
    DateTime outValue = DateTime.MinValue;
    if (time.Length == 6)
       time = "0" + time;
    bool error = DateTime.TryParseExact(time, "HH:mmtt" /*"hh:mmtt"*/, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out outValue);

    Console.WriteLine(error);
    Console.WriteLine(outValue);
    Console.Read();
```

But it's better to go with `H:mmtt` template as pointed by Jamiec

Comment: Yes, you are right, I have defined format by myself. I am going to fill such a 0.

Answer (score 1):

This happends because you write HH:mmtt.
Try this:

```
bool error = DateTime.TryParseExact(time, "H:mm:tt" /*"h:mm:tt"*/,
CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out outValue);
```